# How could I match the three words

Tags: regex, perl

If a word like 'm.john', or 'm_john', or 'mjohn', how could I match all of them?

I tried /\w+/, but obviously, the '.' won't be matched

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more characters to the set of allowed characters by using a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/[\w.]+/
```

The `_` is already matched by `\w`.

Comment: The \w will include digits which the asker may not want.

Comment: @braden.groom: True, but since he had started out with `\w`, I assumed that that's OK with him. Still, good to point this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character class with `.` and `_` , then you make it optional:

```
/m[._]?john/
```

for this particular example

Comment: If his original regex was `\w+`, I doubt he's looking for a literal match of `m.john` now.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: There are so many john on the planet, you never know

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match letters, digits, underscores and periods then you can use this:

```
/[\w.]+/
```

If you dont want to include digits then use this:

```
/[a-zA-Z._]+/
```

If you dont want to match capital letters then leave that part out:

```
/[a-z._]+/
```